# Type error when using controlled datetime picker

Tags: typescript, react-native

How do I set a react state with a event.target.value in a datetime picker?

Here is my code that is not working:

```js
const [ date, setDate ] = useState(new Date());


<input type="datetime-local" className="form-control" onChange={event => setDate(event.target.value)} value={date}/>
```

Here is the error that shows me:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)

Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE]" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` expects the type of provided data to be `string`, currently it is of type `Date`.

Also, it expects the date to be of the format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm`. You can update the state initialization as:

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState<string>(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm"));
```